# Nodejs - data transfer between server and client

Tags: node.js, tcp

I was given a task to send JSON string from client to server and from server to client, whenever there is a new record found to send.
I decided to build TCP connection(suggest me if there is any other better way in Node.js) between server and client to transfer data.
The problem is, I was supposed to use a delimiter to separate JSON strings one from another. I am afraid what if the json string contains the delimiter string inside the object. I am looking for a better way to separate two JSON strings.
Below is my code. Please help me.

**Client**

```
var net = require('net')
    , client = new net.Socket();

var chunk = ''
    , dlim_index = -1
    , delimit = '~~';


client.connect(config.Port, config.IpAddress, function () {
    console.log('Server Connected');
    client.write('CLIENTID:' + process.argv[2]);
    client.write(delimit);
});

client.on('data', function (data) {

    var recvData = data.toString().trim();
    chunk += recvData;
    dlim_index = chunk.indexOf(recvData);
    console.log(data);
    while (dlim_index > -1) {
        var useData = chunk.substring(0, dlim_index);
        if (useData == 'SUCCESS') {
            controller.listenOutQueue(function (dataToSend) {
                var object = JSON.parse(dataToSend);
                client.write(dataToSend);
                client.write(delimit);
            });
        }
        else {
            var record = JSON.parse(useData);
            controller.insertIntoQueue(record, function (status) {
            });
        }
        chunk = chunk.substring(dlim_index + 2);
        dlim_index = chunk.indexOf(delimit);
    }
});

client.on('close', function () {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});

client.setTimeout(50000, function () {
    //client.destroy();
});
```

**Server**

```
var net = require('net')
    , server = net.createServer()
    , delimit = '~~'
    , clients = [];

controller.listenOutQueue(function (dataToSend) {
    client.write(dataToSend);
    client.write(delimit);
});

server.on('connection', function (socket) {
        
   
    var chunk = '';
    var dlim_index = -1;

    socket.on('data', function (data) {

        var recvData = data.toString().trim();
        chunk += recvData;
        dlim_index = chunk.indexOf(delimit);

        while (dlim_index > -1) {
            var useData = chunk.substring(0, dlim_index);
            if (useData.substring(0, 9) == 'CLIENTID:') {
                socket.clientid = useData.replace('CLIENTID:', '');
                console.log('Client Id: ' + socket.clientid);
                clients.push(socket);
                var successMessage = "SUCCESS";
                socket.write(successMessage);
                socket.write(delimit);
            }
            else {

                controller.insertIntoQueue(JSON.parse(useData), function (status) {
                });
            }
            chunk = chunk.substring(dlim_index + 2);
            dlim_index = chunk.indexOf(delimit);
        }
    });

    socket.on('end', function () {
        console.log('Connection Closed (' + socket.clientid + ')');
    });

    socket.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('SOCKET ERROR:', err);
    });

});

server.listen(config.Port, config.IpAddress);
```

Comment: Just use a delimiter that's illegal (or normally would not work) inside JSON like newline. Or the null byte `\0`. Another method is to not use delimiters but count your braces `{}` and `[]` to ensure that a piece of data is complete.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response.

Comment: Also, may I recommend using a 3rd party library that implement a stardard protocol. For example socket.io handle data as messages so you will not need a delimiter. It depends if it's for a real application or just for the exercice of writing into raw TCP streams.

Comment: is it possible to use socket.io in real application, because i might send upto 3MB size json string?